# Passing route name as variable in laravel blade template to go back to previous page dynamically

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php
$pre=app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create(URL::previous()))->getName();
//echo $pre gives `admin.post` which is a valid name in web.php
?>
<a href="{{route($pre) }}"><button class="btn-default btn">Cancel</button></a>
```

Why is the cancel button not working and is throwing error in laravel. The logic here was to go back to previous page. I even stored replaced route in $pre with value of route name `admin.post` but still nothing..

Comment: please show route file

Comment: why don't you just write `<a href='{{URL::previous()}}'>`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but just wanted to try by calling the 'route name' ..Using  <a href='{{URL::previous()}}'> is also appropriate for me either

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$pre=app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create(URL::previous()))->getName();
//echo $pre gives `admin.post` which is a valid name in web.php
?>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ route($pre) }}">Cancel</a>
```

I just changed the button tag to anchor tag with button class and it it is now working..